# Query GPU specification using ManagedCUDA

Tags: c#, cuda, gpgpu

I'm actually looking to query my GPU specification, in a C# application using ManagedCUDA.

So I looked to the documentation and I saw that there is a class named "CudaDeviceProperties" that has a lot of variables set to store date from the GPU.

But I've no idea how to use it. I tried to create the variable like follow :

`CudaDeviceProperties prop = new CudaDeviceProperties();`

And attempting to print for example : `prop.MaxGridDim.x` always return `0`

I didn't see any function like in "real" CUDA to set the class variable with something like : `cudaGetDeviceProperties(*prop, int device)`

So I do some research about a way to query all data I wanted to get with system namespace.. but didn't find a way to get the maxGridDim and maxBlockDim I wanted to have, I got the memory, that actually a good point.

What I want to get :

- max Grid dimension (x, y, z)
- max Block dimension (x, y, z)
- amount of memory (total)
- amount of memory (left)
- amount of memory I can use per block ?

Thanks for any response, tips, or whatever !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in the ManagedCUDA namespace called `GetDeviceInfo` which should return the device information which would be returned by `cudaGetDeviceProperties` in native CUDA.